# How do I reference things from other websites? HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I am putting a weather icon in my website and I have tried weather widgets, but they are not as customizable as I would like. All I want is to reference from a site; the temperature, and whether it is sunny, rainy, etc. I want to then have this data to display on a website.

```html
<div class="Weather">
  <a class="weatherwidget-io" 
      href="https://forecast7.com/en/35d47n97d52/oklahoma-city/?unit=us"
      data-label_1="OKLAHOMA CITY"
      data-label_2="OKLAHOMA"
      data- font="Times New Roman"
      data-icons="Climacons Animated"
      data- mode="Current"
      data-days="3"
      data-theme="pure"
      data- basecolor="">OKLAHOMA CITY OKLAHOMA</a>
  <script>
    ! function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src =
          'https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }
    }(document, 'script', 'weatherwidget-io-js');
  </script>
</div>
```

This is what I have, but i cant control the height of the widget. I think it is locked. But I can scale it, but i makes it extremely fuzzy.

Comment: Can you please post your code about what you have done and what's not working in that?

Comment: check for any existing api

Answer (score 0):

If display options from the widget provider is not enough, write your own widget :-)
It's not that difficult tho, include the axios JS library or AJAX, make an API call and you will have your wanted data. After that, use basic JS to display returned data.
In your case, seems like the provider allows customizing EITHER `width` or `height`. Their Angular do the rest of scaling so we may not expect further customization from that